# super(type,subclass) in simple singleton implementation

Tags: python

when I was implementing naive singleton in python, I came up with a problem with super key word. As usual the behavior of super is always tricky and buggy, hope someone can shed light on it. Thanks :)

The problem is that:

```
class Singleton(object):
    def __new__(cls,*args,**kw):
        if not hasattr(cls,'_instance'):
            #create a instance of type cls,
            origin=super(Singleton,Singleton).__new__(cls,*args,**kw)
            cls._instance=origin
        return cls._instance

class B(Singleton):
    def __init__(self,b):
        self.b=b
```

It actually works, but I am wondering

Will it be better if I change line 5 to the below, like in most of the books?

```
origin=super(Singleton,cls).__new__(cls,*args,**ks)
```

what's the difference to make?

Comment: `super()` may be tricky, but it is *not buggy*. People just misunderstand how it works.

Comment: you could just do `object.__new__(cls,*args,**kw)` which is nice an explicit ... if not necessarily a best practice, however if you did do it the way you suggest I don't think you need to pass cls as the first argument, just `super(Singleton,cls).__new__(*args,**ks)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: no, `__new__` **always** needs that explicit `cls` first argument. It is an [implicit *static* method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), not a class method.

Comment: oh thanks for clarifying ... I dont often use `__new__`

Comment: Note that you probably need to check in `cls.__dict__` for the instance rather than using `hasattr`, which will see an inherited `_instance` attribute if there is one. To see this in action, try making an instance of the base `Singleton` class, then trying to instantiate `B` (you'll get the same `Singleton` instance both times). Inheritance often doesn't make sense with Singletons, which is why Python's built-in singletons (like `None`) and other types with limited numbers of members (like `bool`) don't allow subclassing. Having an `__init__` in a singleton type also doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super()` searches the MRO of the current object for the next class that has the requested attribute. The first argument to `super()` determines the starting point for the MRO search, the second argument determines the object from which to take the MRO.

As long as you don't use *multiple inheritance*, your MRO will be straightforward. `Singleton` will always be in the same location in the MRO in that case. With multiple inheritance, where `Singleton` appears in the MRO of the subclass will differ, and you really want to use `cls` to get the *current* MRO, not the MRO of just `Singleton`.

For your simple example, ignoring `cls` (e.g. `B`) is fine:

```
>>> class Singleton(object):
...     def __new__(cls,*args,**kw):
...         if not hasattr(cls,'_instance'):
...             #create a instance of type cls,
...             origin=super(Singleton,Singleton).__new__(cls,*args,**kw)
...             cls._instance=origin
...         return cls._instance
... 
>>> class B(Singleton):
...     def __init__(self,b):
...         self.b=b
... 
>>> B.__mro__
(<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.Singleton'>, <type 'object'>)
>>> Singleton.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Singleton'>, <type 'object'>)
```

So `super(Singleton, Singleton)` and `super(Singleton, cls)` end up searching through the same sublist, finding only `object`.

Use multiple inheritance however, and you'll get a very *different* MRO; note that `Foo` is listed between `Singleton` and `object`:

```
>>> class Foo(object): pass
... 
>>> class Bar(Singleton, Foo): pass
... 
>>> Bar.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Bar'>, <class '__main__.Singleton'>, <class '__main__.Foo'>, <type 'object'>)
```

If you use `super(Singleton, Singleton)`, then `Foo` is *inadvertently skipped* when looking for inherited methods. `super(Singleton, cls)` will search through `(Foo, object)`, `super(Singleton, Singleton)` will only look at `object`.

Comment: In your last code sample, is `Singleton` inheriting from `Foo` or from `object`?

Comment: @MartinKonecny: it is the same `Singleton` from the question, as used in the first part of the demo session; it inherits from `object`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for your reply. That sentence "The first argument to super() determines the starting point for the MRO search, the second argument determines the object from which to take the MRO." is just brilliant enlightenment. I was trapped in the concept of bound and unbound type of super.